# Spring Security with PrimeFaces Dialog Framework

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I have a web Project which uses Spring security and Primefaces.

I am trying to use Primefaces Dialog Framework to call any XHTML File as a dialog .. my problem is when I add this line on my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The dialog Box doesn't appear , if I remove the line above , the dialog box is being displayed .. but If I remove the lines above , I loose the spring security feature .. any configuration I missed?

Comment: Security frameworks work on HTTP requests whether it is a dialog or something else. You are likely trying to open a secure page insecurely in a dialog or there is likely something wrong in the security configuration file (or corresponding Java code).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Spring Security is blocking the frame generated by Primefaces. You can make it work by adding the following directive to Spring Security configuration

http
    // ...
    .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

source:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-frame-options